# Android ActionBar background (when app is collapsed/minimized)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can't find how to set background color of ActionBar in collapsed state.
In fullscreen/opened state it works well but in collapsed/minimized it always the same gray color (color of android theme i derive from).

I want it to look like in youtube app.
[image]
[image]
Please help me.
Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 7):

Solution found.

Just set color to **android:colorPrimary** property.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:textColorPrimary" tools:targetApi="21">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary" tools:targetApi="21">@color/green_back</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="21">@color/green_back_dark</item>
...
</style>
```

Comment: your piece of sorcery has saved my day! Thanks.

Comment: what abt low level api, i mean 10 ,12 ?